# Inserting an array into a table - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to enter the data that has been provided in an array. and will connect some data. but I'm confused about how to insert it into the table.

```js
var name_id = [1000,1001,1002];
var total = [3000,3100,3200];
var name_data = 
    {
    "1": {
        "1000": {
        "nama": "John Doe",
        "gender": "Male",
     },
    },
    "2": {
        "1001": {
        "nama": "Allen",
        "gender": "Male",
     },
    },
    "3": {
        "1002": {
        "nama": "Karin",
        "gender": "Female",
     },
    },
   }

var id_name = ""
name_id.map((c, i) => {
    id_name += `<tr>
    <td>${c}</td></tr>
`});

var total_vote=""
total.map((c, i) => {
    total_vote += `<tr>
    <td>${c}</td></tr>
`});

var valuex = (Object.values(name_data));
var name_ = Object.keys(name_data).length;
for (var x; x<valuex.length; x++) {
    console.log(valuex[x])
}
//console.log('a',name_)
//var newName = {'1000': 'John',}
//for (var x=0; x<name)




$('#table').append(`
    <tbody>
    ${id_name}
    ${total_vote}
  </tbody>
`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

here is the link for the complete code https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/n2ho6v3L/32/

Any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
var name_id = [1000, 1001, 1002];
var total = [3000, 3100, 3200];
var name_data = {
  "1": {
    "1000": {
      "nama": "John Doe",
      "gender": "Male",
    },
  },
  "2": {
    "1001": {
      "nama": "Allen",
      "gender": "Male",
    },
  },
  "3": {
    "1002": {
      "nama": "Karin",
      "gender": "Female",
    },
  },
}
let tbody = $("<tbody></tbody>");

Object.keys(name_data).forEach(key => {
  let nameId = name_id[key-1];
  tbody.append("<tr><td>"+name_data[key][nameId].nama+"</td><td>"+ total[key-1]+"</td></tr>");  
})
$('#table').append(tbody);
```